# A good phrase/verb to replace "introduce"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am giving a presentation to introduce the career path of bioinformatics researchers to a group of Ph.D. students.

In the presentation abstract I have:

> I will [introduce] the responsibilities and skill sets of a bioinformatics researcher.

I feel the word "introduce" is inappropriate. I am also considering "dig into".

What are some alternative phrases to express that I'll "discuss the role in detail"?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial research efforts. For example, what does a thesaurus say about possible synonyms for *introduce*? I strongly encourage you to take the sitie [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: What are you trying to express? *Introduce* and *dig in* have very different meanings, so it's odd that you've considered both of them. And what's wrong with just using *discuss*?

Comment: "I will ['explain' or 'outline'] the responsibilities ..."

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider "outline." See the definition below:

> If you **outline** an idea or a plan, you explain it in a general way ([source](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/outline)).

However, the verb *to outline* is about explaining something in general, not discussing something in detail.

So, perhaps, *to go into something* is more appropriate:

> If you **go into** something, you describe or examine it fully or in detail ([source](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go-into)):
>
> 1. I will not *go into these texts* in any depth as I am sure that many of
>      you will want to comment on various provisions.
> 2. I won't *go into too much description* of any of these projects.
> 3. I will not *go into any substantive analysis* of this draft resolution.

So, I suggest the following: "I'd like to go into description of the responsibilities and skill sets of a bioinformatics researcher" (in case you really want to pay much attention to the issue).

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest the word **expound** *on/upon*. Associated synonyms are *explain, run through, define, put across, clarify* etc.

**Expound**  (verb) https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expound

> **to give a detailed explanation of something** *Or* **to explain by setting forth in careful and often elaborate detail**
>
> > 1. He continued to expound on the failings of our educational system.
> > 2. Expound a law.

Your sentence: 
`I will expound on/run through the responsibilities and skill sets of a bioinformatics researcher.`

Answer (score 0):

How about the word "explain"?

In a presentation, it's important to grab your listeners' attention quickly. You can definitely do that with simpler words.

So it's —

I will [explain] the responsibilities and skill sets of a bioinformatics researcher.